# Edit FIeld - center and with numeric keypad in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, textbox, textfield, blackberry-simulator

I want a text field, which is using for enter numbers. I want to make it center. And want to allow it with numeric keypad.

It was working fine with BB OS 5 and when using BB OS 6 / 7 / 7.1, I was unable to show numeric keypad.

Follwing is the code:

```
txtEventNumber = new RichTextField(RichTextField.TEXT_ALIGN_HCENTER) {
public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
super.paint(graphics);
int oldColor = Color.GRAY;
graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
graphics.setColor(TEXT_COLOR);
Font font = this.getFont().derive(Font.EMBOSSED_EFFECT, 20);
this.setFont(font);
graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 10, 10);
graphics.setColor(oldColor);
super.paint(graphics);
}
public int getPreferredHeight() {
return super.getPreferredHeight() + ADD_MARGIN;
}
protected void onFocus(int direction) {
if (Touchscreen.isSupported() && getScreen().getVirtualKeyboard() != null)
// Show keyboard
getScreen().getVirtualKeyboard().setVisibility(VirtualKeyboard.SHOW);
};
protected void onUnfocus() {
if (Touchscreen.isSupported() && getScreen().getVirtualKeyboard() != null)
// Hide keyboard
getScreen().getVirtualKeyboard().setVisibility(VirtualKeyboard.HIDE_FORCE);
};
};
txtEventNumber.setEditable(true);
// can enter only numeric digits
if (Touchscreen.isSupported())
// show numeric keypad
txtEventNumber.setFilter(TextFilter.get(TextFilter.DEFAULT_SMART_PHONE));
else
txtEventNumber.setFilter(TextFilter.get(TextFilter.REAL_NUMERIC));
txtEventNumber.setMargin(10, 10, 0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a HFM and adding the edit field into it.
Also setting the cursor position at each key operation using `keyChar()` method.

That's why I set the cursor position at center with virtual numeric keypad using edit field.

Also thanks for all.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Horizontal/Vertical Field manager, Then set it as Center. Then addd the editField to it.

```
EditField e=new EditField(label, initial value, max char limit, BasicEditField.FILTER_INTEGER);
```

Comment: It is fine to show numeric virtual keyboard.
But when adding it to Horizontal Field manager, it was not showing field in center. Also note that I am using **OS 7/7.1**. I have used HFM as follows:

`HorizontalFieldManager hfmTxtNumber = new HorizontalFieldManager(NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | Field.FIELD_HCENTER);`

Comment: change to HorizontalFieldManager hfmTxtNumber = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER); then try.

Comment: It's also not working. I was able to make it center as per above code(using RichTextField) but at that time it was not showing virtual Numeric keyboard. I have also tried different filter methods such as TextFilter.Numeric etc

Comment: combine my code to yours. My code showing numeric keypad na. so use it in your code.

Comment: Signare, please post your code as answer so that I can use it.